# recv on socket causes 100% cpu usage

Tags: sockets

A client application needs to be running non-stop and should be tolerant to server and communication issues.

But it seldom hangs, using 100% CPU.

Once i've been able to attach a gdb server when the issue occurred after two weeks running and the back trace was:

```
__syscall_cp_c
recvfrom
recv
```

The context of the `recv` call is:

```c
while (1) {
  int socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  int flag = 1;
  setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &flag, sizeof(flag));
  struct timeval timeo = { .tv_sec = 4 };
  setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeo, sizeof(timeo));
  setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &timeo, sizeof(timeo));
  connect(socket, &in_addr, sizeof(in_addr));
  
  while (!error) {
    send(socket, data, length, 0);

    uint8_t buf[4096];
    unsigned offs = 0;
    while (offs < len) {
      ssize_t rc = recv(socket, buf + offs, sizeof(buf) - offs, 0);
      if (rc < 0) { error = 1; break; }
      offs += rc;
    }
    
    clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 1 * second);
  }

  shutdown(socket, SHUT_RDWR);
  close(socket);
}
```

The above code has been shortened to just show code related with the socket and removed most error checking. The actual code checks for all errors and when anything fails the socket is closed and reopenned again.

gdb reported that `offs` was greater than zero and smaller than `len`, so, the inner loop was at least on its second iteration when it hanged.

The application is single-threaded, running on embedded linux with the musl libc on arm64.

Please, can you help me debugging the issue?

Comment: You aren't checking for the case when `recv()` returns zero, so you are looping forever when the peer disconnects.

Comment: `sizeof(buf) - offs` should be `len - offs` instead (provided that `len <= sizeof(buf)`). Bu, where is `len` declared and assigned?

Comment: @user207421, what an oversight from my part, you are absolutely correct. The man page indeed says that 0 is a possble return value.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, i am using the buffer size instead of the expected response length because in this case receiving more data than expected is also considered an error.

Comment: No point in reading it though. Just close the socket.